# specifying plugins in rails breaks gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

In my environment I'm specifying plugins:

> config.plugins = [:foo, :bar]

However this seems to be breaking gems. In particular, it's affecting hotpoad, haml and possibly mechanize, which are included with config.gem.

For haml, its no longer looking for .haml files. For hotpoad, errors are no longer being logged. If I remove the config.plugins line or add in :all this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `config.plugins = [:foo, :bar, :all]` to ensure everything which hasn't been explicitly named gets included.

Comment: I want to selectively load plugins. If it's not in the vendor/plugin folder, why do I need to still include it?